# glTexSubImage2D performance oddity

Tags: performance, opengl, driver, nvidia

I was curious to see the performance of texture uploads with my configuration using OpenGL and noticed something I think is odd. I create a 4K texture using `glTexStorage2D` with a format of `GL_RGBA8`. Then, every frame I use `glTexSubImage2D` to re-upload a static image buffer to the texture. Based off the frame rate I get about 5.19GB/s. Next, I changed the format of the texture to `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` and re-try the experiment. This time I am getting 2.81GB/s, a significant decrease. This seems odd because as far as I know there shouldn't be anything different about uploading sRGB data verses uploading RGB data, as there is no conversion that should be taking place (sRGB conversion should take place in the shader, during sampling).

Some additional information. For the first test I use `GL_RGBA` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` in the call to `glTexSubImage2D`, as this is what the driver (through `glGetInternalformativ`) tells me is ideal. For the second test I use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`, as per the drivers suggestion. A bit of testing confirms that these are the fastest formats to use respectively. This is using a Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 on Windows 7 x64 using the 332.21 drivers.

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#define SCREEN_SIZE_X 1024
#define SCREEN_SIZE_Y 1024

#define GLSL(src) "#version 440 core\n" #src

const char* vertex_shader = GLSL(
    const vec2 data[4] = vec2[]
    (
        vec2(-1.0,  1.0),
        vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
        vec2( 1.0,  1.0),
        vec2( 1.0, -1.0)
    );

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(data[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0);
    }
);

const char* fragment_shader = GLSL(
    layout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D texture0;
    layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 screenSize;
    out vec4 frag_color;

    void main()
    {
        frag_color = texture(texture0, gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize);
    }
);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_SIZE_X, SCREEN_SIZE_Y, "OpenGL Texture Upload", nullptr, nullptr);

    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(0);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    GLuint shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fs);
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vs);
    glLinkProgram(shader_program);
    glUseProgram(shader_program);

    glProgramUniform2f(shader_program, 1, SCREEN_SIZE_X, SCREEN_SIZE_Y);

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
#ifdef USE_SRGB
    glTextureStorage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 4096, 4096);
#else
    glTextureStorage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 4096, 4096);
#endif
    glTextureParameteriEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTextureParameteriEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTextureParameteriEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTextureParameteriEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindMultiTextureEXT(GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glProgramUniform1i(shader_program, 0, 0);

    std::vector<unsigned int> image_buffer(4096*4096, 0xFF0000FFul);

    double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
    double nbFrames = 0;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
        nbFrames++;
        if (currentTime - lastTime >= 1.0)
        {
            char cbuffer[50];
            snprintf(cbuffer, sizeof(cbuffer), "OpenGL Texture Upload [%.1f fps, %.3f ms]", nbFrames, 1000.0 / nbFrames);
            glfwSetWindowTitle(window, cbuffer);
            nbFrames = 0;
            lastTime++;
        }
#ifdef USE_SRGB
        glTextureSubImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 4096, 4096, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, image_buffer.data());
#else
        glTextureSubImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 4096, 4096, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, image_buffer.data());
#endif
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is such a thing as a 'native pixel format'. Look at [this link from Nvidia](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter32.html), especially section 32.1.3.

Comment: This isn't the explanation. For one, `glGetInternalformativ` recommends `GL_RGBA` in both cases, not `GL_BGRA`. Secondly, experimentation shows that `GL_BGRA` is not faster in either cases.